# java 2d array comparing UPDATED

Tags: java, arrays

(UPDATED)
I'm having trouble figuring out what to do here, i need to compare a 2d array that to see if any of the numbers match.  I need four numbers to match either up/down, left/right, or diagonal.  I just can't get it to test for the down/left diagonal ( / ) here is my updated code

```
public static boolean isAdjacentFour( int[][] a ) {
    // Code to test if column has four adjacent numbers
    for ( int row = 0; row <= a.length - 3 ; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col <= a[0].length - 1 ; col++) {
            if (a[row][col] == a[row+1][col] && a[row+2][col] == a[row][col]
                    && a[row+3][col] == a[row][col]) {
                return true;
            } 
        }
    }
    // Code to test if row has four adjacent numbers
    for ( int row = 0; row <= a.length - 1 ; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col <= a[0].length - 3 ; col++) {
            if (a[row][col] == a[row][col+1] && a[row][col] == a[row][col+2]
                    && a[row][col] == a[row][col+3]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
        // Code to test if there are 4 adjacent numbers in a down/right ( \ )diagonal
        for ( int row = 0; row <= a.length - 3 ; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col <= a[0].length - 3 ; col++) {
                if (a[row][col] == a[row+1][col+1] && a[row][col] == a[row+2][col+2]
                        && a[row][col] == a[row+3][col+3] ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        for ( int row = 0; row <= a.length - 3 ; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col <= a[0].length + 3 ; col--) {
                if (a[row][col] == a[row+1][col-1] && a[row][col] == a[row+2][col-2]
                        && a[row][col] == a[row+3][col-3] ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: `[row+2]` and `[row+3]` are the cause of the errors, set the loop condition to `row < a.length -3`

Comment: The comment above is correct, except in my answer I do row <= a.length - 4 to fix it instead but both are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one problem I noticed in the first nested for loop is this line of code,

```
for ( int row = 0; row <= a.length - 3 ; row++)
```

The way you have it now, the row variable is going to be incremented with each iteration of the outer for loop. However, with how you're executing your program, the condition should be `row <= a.length - 4` and here's why. Suppose you had a four by four 2D array. The nested for loop will go through one normal iteration of the inner loop, which actually checks every single column for possible matches of four consecutive matching numbers in a column. Here's what it looks like when actually running the program starting at the outer for loop and row = 0,

Iteration One of the inner for loop:

```
if (a[0][0] == a[1][0] && a[2][0] == a[0][0] && a[3][0] == a[0][0])
```

Iteration Two of the inner for loop:

```
if (a[0][1] == a[1][1] && a[2][1] == a[0][1] && a[3][1] == a[0][1])
```

Iteration Three of the inner for loop:

```
if (a[0][2] == a[1][2] && a[2][2] == a[0][2] && a[3][2] == a[0][2])
```

Last Iteration of the inner for loop:

```
if (a[0][0] == a[1][3] && a[2][3] == a[0][3] && a[3][0] == a[0][3])
```

Once this is done, the row variable will be incremented according to the outer loop definition. This is what is most likely causing an error because now as we start iterating through the inner loop with row = 1, this happens

Iteration One of the inner for loop:

```
if (a[1][0] == a[2][0] && a[3][0] == a[1][0] && a[4][0] == a[1][0])
```

Here, we already have an indexoutofboundsexception when trying to access the 5th row in a 4x4 2D array. So the simple fix here is to change

`for(int row = 0; row <= a.length - 3 ; row++)`

to

```
for(int row = 0; row <= a.length - 4 ; row++)`
```

A similar argument can be made for the second nested for loop. If you don't believe me, do something similar to what I did for the rows and write out the iterations for it using a 4x4 2D array. You'll get the arrayindexoutofbounds exception in the first iteration of the outer for loop and in the second iteration of the inner for loop when row = 0 and col = 1, causing the program to make a check at the fifth column in the first row of a 2D array. So the simple fix should be to change

```
for (int col = 0; col <= a[0].length - 3 ; col++)
```

to

```
for (int col = 0; col <= a[row].length - 4 ; col++)
```

Personally, I prefer to use a[row].length only because there could be some instances where it's not a perfect nxn 2D array. For example, some rows may have only 3 columns where the first row has 7 columns. If this is the case, then you'll get an outofbounds exception for trying to access columns that exist in the first row that don't exist in other rows.

For the third nested for loop, again, same argument can be made just by writing out the iterations and it should be changed to

```
for(int row = 0; row <= a.length - 4 ; row++) {
      for(int col = 0; col <= a[row].length - 4 ; col++)
```

The last nested for loop has a logic problem pertaining to the inner for loop. Since you're decrementing from 0, you're going to get an out of bounds exception just from trying to access negative indices in the array. So the simple fix should be to initialize `col` to the last column and change the condition to col being greater than or equal to `3` since you're accessing elements at the columns, col, col-1, col-2, and col-3. If that is confusing, think about it this way. You're checking columns starting from col and the three that come before it. What if there aren't even four columns to begin with? This is why there's the condition `col >= 3` because you check a column and the three that come before it until you've reached column #4 (col = 3). Once you've reached column #3 (col = 2), there's no way of checking that column and the three before because there are only 3 columns to check at this point. Changes similar to the other 3 nested loops should be made to `for ( int row = 0; row <= a.length - 3 ; row++)` regarding the -3. It should end up looking like this,

```
for ( int row = 0; row <= a.length - 4 ; row++) {
            for (int col = a[row].length - 1; col >= 3; col--)
```

Comment: Thank you... this helped

Comment: Anytime, if u found the answer helpful please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark. Also, if u need any further clarification just ask!

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb , always put debug points to see why you are getting exception/error.

The issue here is your outer loop runs from 0 to row-1 . But inside in inner loop you are using [row+2] and [row+3] and [row+1] . Now when the outer loop goes to row-2 iteration , you will get a out of bound exception.

Can post the code here , but if you understand this , you should be able to solve it.

(EDIT) : example as asked in comment.

assume you  have a 2D array A[][]of size 10X10 .
Now if the current loop is at A[4][4] or (A[row][col])   : 
left element : A[4][3] or (A[row][col-1])   // here we are  at same row but (column -1) as we want the left element.
top-right element :  A[3][5] or ((A[row-1][col+1])   //  here we are going to (4-1) row as we are interested in above row and (4+1)column as we want right element. 
bottom-left:  A[5][3] (A[row+1][col-1]) ...

Now the two consecutive bottom-left elements will be (A[row+1][col-1]) and (A[row+2][col-2]).

Try visualizing it  by drawing a 2D array and naming each cell in terms of A[i][j].

Comment: @11thdimension, and k1133 this helps a lot... now I just have one problem comparing diagonal I have no problem got down and to the right ( \ ), i just can't get it to go down and to the left ( / )

Comment: If I understand correctly , given an element you want to get value of its all neighbours( left , right , up , down ,  top-left,top-right... ) ?

Comment: isn't that what i did in my updated code, im still getting an index out of bounds.... i've tried messing around with the for loop in a bunch of different ways still can't figure it out

Comment: make row <= a.length - 3 as row <a.length - 3 , as numbering of elements start from 0.